# how to get each element of this array in java using android stuio

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, ksoap2

I get the string of array on **responseJSON** like this

```
Result: responseJSON = ["Product1","Product2","Product1","Product2"]

try {
        // Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+methName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to static variable
        responseJSON = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

how can to get each element of the array so that I can use it to display on my `ListView`?

Thanks

```
public void invokeJSONWS(String country, String methName) {
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methName);
    /*
    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo paramPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Name
    paramPI.setName("country");
    // Set Value
    paramPI.setValue(country);
    // Set dataType
    paramPI.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(paramPI);
    */
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+methName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to static variable
        responseJSON = response.toString();

        JSONArray responseArr = new JSONArray(responseJSON);
        for(int i=0;i < responseArr.length();i++)
        {
            String temp=responseArr.getString(i);
            myProduct.add(new Product(responseJSON,2,R.drawable.user_awake,responseJSON));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is the method that i used it it correct that i also include the adding an item in the list view??

please help

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: problem here is you are adding responseJSON in your object instead of temp variable which you have parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass this string to `JSONAarry` constructor like this

```
    ArrayList<String> mParsedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONAarry responseArr=new JSONArray(responseJSON);
    for(int i=0;i<responseArr.length;i++)
    {
       String temp=responseArr.getString(i);// get one by one element 
       myProduct.add(new Product(temp,2,R.drawable.user_awake,responseJSON));
  }
```

Comment: Array type expected; found:'org.json.JSONArray'

Comment: that was typo. I have updated my answer please check it.

Comment: it can parse the number of elements but when i-run the app the string did not parse i get ["Product1","Product2","Product1","Product2"]  each item onthe list view instead of Product1 on the first itemin the list view and so on

Comment: can you post your parsing method here ?

Comment: add `temp` to instead of `responseJSON`  check it now

Comment: you are adding responseJSON instead of temp in your code.